# Typescript NPM package submodules

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I would like to break up my NPM package in to more workable parts.

In my application requiring the package, instead of

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-package'
```

I want

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-package/submodule'
```

My package has a number of files in `src` folder and then an `index.ts` which just exports them all.

`package.json` `main` points to `dist/index.js` already.

My package builds to `dist` directory so

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-package/dist/submodule'
```

and

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-package'
```

both work.

One solution may be to copy all compiled files to package root but this feels untidy.

Maybe there is a way make the dist folder the root? I can't find this in the documentation.

D3 and Lodash manages this but I *think* it's done at build time. I couldn't work out how they managed it.

Comment: There is a nice discussion here about it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305
If you decide to do it in build time with a script, you can check this one: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/scripts/copy-files.js

Comment: For a similar case I used Rollup in order to put one single JS file per sub-module in the package directory. And I managed to build a single definition file `.d.ts` for each JS bundle (with the same file name).

Comment: Thanks guys. I hadn't come across that specific discussion but had come across similar suggestions. It sort of feels like there should either be an easier way to do it or it's not an advisable way to go.